# Convert System.Collections.GenericList'1 [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken] List to Json Array c#

Tags: c#, json, linq

I want to Convert `System.Collections.GenericList'1 [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]` to JSON array.

Initially i had my **JSON Array string** stored in `myData` as below:

```
var myData = l.GetJsonData();
```

Now then i **filtered** my `Json` with the help of `LINQ` as below :

```
 var root = JToken.Parse(myData);
    var study_year = "2016/2017";
    var term = 2;var values = root.Where(t =>
 (int?)t["term"] == term && (string)t["study_year"] == study_year).ToList();
```

Now `values` is the one with sorted data but not in Json Format it shows `System.Collections.GenericList'1[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]`, how can i make it display the sorted data in Json Array string .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simply just  add the following below:**

```
 var values = root.Where(t =>
     (int?)t["term"] == term && (string)t["study_year"] == study_year).ToList();
    var filteredJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the list create a `JArray` with the list as the constructor argument. Once you've got the JArray just call ToString().

```
    var root = JToken.Parse("[ {\"name\" : \"a\", value : 40 },{\"name\" : \"b\", value : 10 }, {\"name\" : \"c\", value : 25 }  ]");

    var filtered = root.Where(t => (int?)t["value"] > 15 ).ToList();

    var jArray = new JArray(filtered);

    Console.WriteLine(jArray.ToString());
```

The above will output the below

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "value": 40
  },
  {
    "name": "c",
    "value": 25
  }
]
```